# Dialogfragment doesn't show up, gets submitted automatically

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to show a DialogFragment when the user submits a form in an Android application.

This is the code that I am executing on the submit button's click.

```
System.out.println("I have reached here.");
            Dialogbox db = Dialogbox.newInstance(ABC", "Completed?", "Yes", "No");
            db.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "SubmitDialog");

            if (null != recorder) {
                recorder.stopRecording();
            }
            saveDetails();
            finish();

            System.out.println("I have reached here.");
```

In logcat I can see the logs saying "I have reached here." twice. The values get inserted into the database too.

I think this is happening because Android doesn't wait for the user to press "Yes" or "No" on the Dialogbox. It continues executing the code and when it hits the

```
   finish()
```

statement it takes the child activity back to the parent activity.

Can someone tell me how should I prevent this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you calling finish() here, you can perform this action inside the dialog fragment.

Comment: Ah! Your comment has just given me the solution! Thanks a tonnes! I'll put all the code in the button click events of the DialogFragment. Thanks again!